# Return 1 value to the function with multiple return values in golang

Tags: go, multiple-return-values

I want to return just 1 value to the function with multiple return values.
I tried this:

```
func myFunc() (int, int){
    return _, 3
}
```

But it didn't work and raised this error: cannot use _ as value

I already know that It's possible to receive one of the returned values.

Is there any way to return just 1 value?

Comment: `Is there any way to return just 1 value?` Plain and simple: No.

Comment: See [proposal: return blank identifier as zero value](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11732).

Comment: Could you elaborate why you  would that? Why not remove one return value from signature of you're not using it?

Comment: I didn't know it's impossible, so I chose wrong algorithm that use both returned values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) for the other return parameters:

```
func myFunc() (int, int){
    return 0, 3
}
```

If you use [named result](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types) parameters, you may also do:

```
func myFunc() (x, y int){
    y = 3
    return
}
```

In this case `x` will also be the zero value of its type, `0` in case of `int`.

You could also write a helper function which adds a dummy return value, e.g.:

```
func myFunc() (int, int) {
    return extend(3)
}

func extend(i int) (int, int) {
    return 0, i
}
```

But personally I don't think it's worth it. Just return the zero value for "unused" return parameters.

Comment: Either one can change function signature, or, if this is an external contract, then the return value is lost likely used.